# Shift selection c# optimization

Tags: c#, wpf, optimization, shift

Basically I have done a code which works as a shift selection, I have already programmed the file selection working with Ctrl-Key selection, but it is required to optimize it. Nevertheless I have not found any way to make it easier has anyone any idea of how could I achieve that? The *highlightedIndex* is a list of *int*.

```
    private int lastClickedPointIdx = -1;
    int firstvaluepoint = 0;
    private int movingPointIdx = -1; //-1: no point moving

    private void KeySelection()
    {
        bool shiftclick = false;
        int firstselectedpoint = 0;
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)) //Ctrl
        {
            if (highlightedIndex.Contains(movingPointIdx)) //remove point if already is in the highlightedIndex list
            {
                highlightedIndex.Remove(movingPointIdx);
                firstselectedpoint = movingPointIdx;
                shiftclick = false;
                return;
            }
            else //otherwise add it to the highlightedIndex list
            {
                highlightedIndex.Add(movingPointIdx);
                highlightedIndex.Sort();
                firstselectedpoint = movingPointIdx;
                shiftclick = false;
            }
        }
        else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift)) //Shift
        {
            if (!shiftclick)
            {
                highlightedIndex.Clear();
                shiftclick = true;
            }            
            if (lastClickedPointIdx > -1) //highlights all points 
            {                            
                if (firstvaluepoint > firstselectedpoint)
                {
                    for (int i = firstselectedpoint; i <= firstvaluepoint; i++)
                    {
                        highlightedIndex.Add(i);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = firstvaluepoint; i <= firstselectedpoint; i++)
                    {
                        highlightedIndex.Add(i);
                    }
                }                                                        
            }
        }
        lastClickedPointIdx = movingPointIdx;
        if (!shiftclick)
            firstvaluepoint = firstselectedpoint; 
    }
```

Comment: Unless you have a specific problem that you need help with, you're probably better off posting on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). See [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211790/393366).

Comment: @BrootsWaymb thank you very much I am kind of new and did not know that. That is what I was looking for

Comment: You should read Code Review's [how to ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting there..